# $p_{ii}^{(2n)}=1$ and $p_{ii}^{(2n+1)}=0$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, markov-chains

I learnt the concept of the period of state i for DTMC and I'm wondering

- why we have $p_{ii}^{(2n)}=1$ and $p_{ii}^{(2n+1)}=0$?
- if $d(i)=p$ then $p_{ii}^{(pn)}=1$ and $p_{ii}^{(pn+1)}=0$?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: states 1 and 3 are transient.  2 and 4 form a single (recurrent) communicating class and a bipartite graph -- draw this and write out the transition matrix.  Hence $p_{ii}^{(2n)}=1$ and $p_{ii}^{(2n+1)}=0$

Comment: why exactly equal one, is it because it is absorbing state ?

Comment: I will repeat my comment: draw the graph and write out the transition matrix for the recurrent class containing just states 2 and 4.  After you've dropped the transition matrix into your original post, let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Thank you i see where 1 comes from ( Stochastic matrix ) but still have problem why p^{2n}=1 and p^{2n+1}=0 and if d(i)=p can we say that p^{2p}=1 and p^{2p+1}=0 Could you answer my question by elaborating more?

Comment: I see essentially zero effort in your original post.  It consists almost entirely of an image which is deprecated as not searchable and not usable for those using a screen reader.  You still have not done what I've asked which is to drop in the transition matrix for the recurrent class comprising just states 2 and 4 in your original post.  I am done here.